# How to auto populate a series of weekly dates in one column

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

I would like to generate a series of dates in the A column. Example is A1 would be Jan 11, 2016 - Jan 17, 2016. Then A2 would be Jan 18, 2016 - Jan 24, 2016. Then continue to fill by week down for one year. Can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

Try this.  Put text 'Jan 11, 2016 - Jan 17, 2016' without quotes  in Cell A1. Now in A2 copy this formula and copy it down the column.

```
=CONCATENATE(CONCATENATE(TEXT(MID(A1,SEARCH("-",A1,1)+2,LEN(A1))+1,"MMM")," ",DAY(MID(A1,SEARCH("-",A1,1)+2,LEN(A1))+1),", ",YEAR(MID(A1,SEARCH("-",A1,1)+2,LEN(A1))+1))," - ",CONCATENATE(TEXT(MID(A1,SEARCH("-",A1,1)+2,LEN(A1))+7,"MMM")," ",DAY(MID(A1,SEARCH("-",A1,1)+2,LEN(A1))+7),", ",YEAR(MID(A1,SEARCH("-",A1,1)+2,LEN(A1))+7)))
```